# Redux-form: update/change two fields values at once

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would like to change two fields values of a form at once in Redux-Form.
There exists a change method, but it allows change only one field. 
Is there any way how to change more then one field value at once, please?

Ex.

```
Fields:
  - patternType
  - color
```

I would like to set both fields at once.

Comment: Hey! How's it going? Did you find a solution yourself? Would be nice to hear if my answer was useful at all, or if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass onChange callback to Field component and along with change action you can:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const TwoFieldsForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, change } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field
            name="someField"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            onChange={(event, newValue) => change("otherField", newValue)}
          />
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'form' 
})(TwoFieldsForm)
```

see in the [docs](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-onchange-event-newvalue-previousvalue-name-gt-void-code-optional-)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there's a better way but this way works if you want two change the value of two inputs, based on the change of just one:

```js
const Form = ({change, dispatch}) => {
    const onFirstChange = (event) => {
      const text = event.target.value;
      // make change actions for both inputs
      const changeFirst = change('first', text);
      const changeSecond = change('second', text + text.toUpperCase());
      // dispatch them for both
      dispatch(changeFirst);
      dispatch(changeSecond);
  };
  return (<div>
    First: <Field name='first' component='input' type='text' onChange={onFirstChange} /><br />
    Second: <Field name='second' component='input' type='text' />
  </div>
    )
};

const MyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'foo'
})(Form);

// END EXAMPLE
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <MyForm />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**JSFiddle demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/399cpnz1/1/

Comment: you used two calls of change, this is not solution

Comment: I can see why you would say that. It depends on how you read the question. It's two calls, but they are triggered by just one onChange event, so for the user the two inputs will be updated "at once". Unfortunately the jsfiddle link seems broken now, but at the time I posted it worked just fine.